# Add # to submenu URLs automatically

Tags: menus, urls

I'm trying to replace all my child page URLs to include a # automatically

example: http://www.website.com/parentfoo/#childfoo

I tried using `wp_setup_nav_menu_item` to run through all the child menu items and add '#' to it but now $menu_item->post_name brings up the ID so I don't know how to replace the string correctly.

What I have so far:

```
function auto_hashtag( $menu_item ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $menu_item->post_parent > 0) {

        // url
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        // slug
        $slug = $menu_item->post_name;
        $menu_item->url = str_replace($slug, "#"+$slug, $url);
    }

    return $menu_item;
}
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'auto_hashtag' );
```

Comment: can you give some of the current HTML output you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up doing the trick.

```
function auto_hashtag( $menu_item ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $menu_item->post_parent > 0) {

        // url
        $url = $menu_item->url;
        $menu_item->url = preg_replace('!/([^/]+)/$!', "/#\\1", $url);
    }

    return $menu_item;
}
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'auto_hashtag' );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems like a bad idea; the `#` symbol is used at the end of a URL to denote an anchor position for the website to scroll to.

Take for example this very page with this link:

[Add # to submenu URLs automatically](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141264/add-to-submenu-urls-automatically/#post-form)

When clicked, it moved the screen down to the `<div>` tag with an `id` of `post-form`.

In the example you give `http://www.website.com/parentfoo/#childfoo` , the browser would go to the page 'parentfoo' and look for a HTML element with the `id` of `childfoo`.

It would be a bad idea to change all the default URL rewriting to account for your wanted url structure.

In other words, your Child page URLs would not be child page URLs any longer if you continue.

MAYBE I JUST DO NOT UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO ??

Comment: That's what I need to do in the context of how my site is being built. I'm taking all the child pages and loading them in the parent as one long page. When you click on the subpages, you would scroll down the page. Like this: http://themes.opendept.net/retro-portfolio/#about-me


Why I'm doing this, is so my client can make subpages, and it'll automatically setup the anchors for him without ever going into the admin nav.

Comment: I see, let me take another look at your function.

Comment: I just posted a solution that I found to work

Comment: Glad you got it working